# Use of the GPU on Colab with pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory, mnist

I am trying to use the GPU on Colab, but it takes about 400 seconds to train my model when I use GPU and 200 seconds to train it when I select CPU, so I think there is a problem somewhere..

Where did I made a mistake ?

```
import torch
from torch import Tensor
import dlc_practical_prologue as prologue
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


dev = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print(dev)

#%% Exercise1

def sigma(x):
    return torch.tanh(x)

def dsigma(x):
    return 1-torch.pow(torch.tanh(x), 2)

#%% Exercise2

def loss(v, t):    
    return torch.sum(torch.pow(t-v, 2))

def dloss(v, t):
    #print(v.size(), t.size())
    return -2*(t-v)


#%% Exercise3

def forward_pass(w1, b1, w2, b2, x):
    s1 = w1.mv(x) + b1
    x1 = sigma(s1)
    #print(b1.size())
    s2 = w2.mv(x1) + b2
    x2 = sigma(s2)
    #print(s2.size(), x2.size())
    return x, s1 , x1, s2, x2


def backward_pass(w1, b1, w2, b2, t, x, s1, x1, s2, x2, dl_dw1, dl_db1, dl_dw2, dl_db2):
    #print(dl_db2.size(), (dsigma(s2) * dloss(x2, t)).size())
    dl_db2_temp = dsigma(s2) * dloss(x2, t)
    dl_dw2_temp = dl_db2_temp.unsqueeze(0).t() * x1.unsqueeze(0)
    dl_db1_temp = w2.t().mv(dl_db2_temp)
    dl_dw1_temp = dl_db1_temp.unsqueeze(0).t() * x.unsqueeze(0)
    return dl_dw1 + dl_dw1_temp, dl_db1 + dl_db1_temp, dl_dw2 + dl_dw2_temp, dl_db2 + dl_db2_temp


#%% Exercise4

train_data, train_target, test_data, test_target = prologue.load_data(cifar = False, one_hot_labels = True, normalize = True, flatten = True)

train_data = train_data.to(dev)
train_target = train_target.to(dev)
test_data = test_data.to(dev)
test_target = test_target.to(dev)

train_target = train_target * 0.9
test_target = test_target * 0.9
print(train_target.is_cuda)

epsilon = 1e-6
w1 = torch.empty((50, 784), device=dev).normal_(0, epsilon)
b1 = torch.empty((50), device=dev).normal_(0, epsilon)
w2 = torch.empty((10, 50), device=dev).normal_(0, epsilon)
b2 = torch.empty((10), device=dev).normal_(0, epsilon)
print(w1.is_cuda)

dl_dw1 = torch.zeros((50, 784), device=dev)
dl_db1 = torch.zeros((50), device=dev)  
dl_dw2 = torch.zeros((10, 50), device=dev)  
dl_db2 = torch.zeros((10), device=dev)  

eta = 0.1 / train_target.size(0)
nb_simul = 1000
error_train = torch.zeros(nb_simul, device=dev)
error_test = torch.zeros(nb_simul, device=dev)

t1 = time.time()

for i in range(nb_simul):
    dl_dw1 = torch.zeros((50, 784), device=dev)
    dl_db1 = torch.zeros((50), device=dev)  
    dl_dw2 = torch.zeros((10, 50), device=dev)  
    dl_db2 = torch.zeros((10), device=dev)

    for j in range(train_target.size(0)):
        x, s1 , x1, s2, x2 = forward_pass(w1, b1, w2, b2, train_data[j])
        #print(x.is_cuda)
        #print(x2.is_cuda)
        dl_dw1, dl_db1, dl_dw2, dl_db2 = backward_pass(w1, b1, w2, b2, train_target[j], x, s1, x1, s2, x2, dl_dw1, dl_db1, dl_dw2, dl_db2)
        #print(dl_dw1.is_cuda)

    w1 = w1 - eta * dl_dw1
    w2 = w2 - eta * dl_dw2
    b1 = b1 - eta * dl_db1
    b2 = b2 - eta * dl_db2
    #print(w1.is_cuda)
    


    for j in range(train_target.size(0)):
        x_train, s1_train, x1_train, s2_train, x2_train = forward_pass(w1, b1, w2, b2, train_data[j])
        _, predict = x2_train.max(0)
        _, value = train_target[j].max(0)
        if predict != value:
            error_train[i] += 1
    
    #print('error on training: ', error_train)


    for j in range(test_target.size(0)):
        x_test, s1_test, x1_test, s2_test, x2_test = forward_pass(w1, b1, w2, b2, test_data[j])
        _, predict = x2_test.max(0)
        _, value = test_target[j].max(0)
        if predict != value:
            error_test[i] += 1

    #print('error on test: ', error_test)


t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)

#%% Plot

abs_x = torch.arange(1, nb_simul+1, 1)
plt.plot(abs_x, error_train)
plt.plot(abs_x, error_test)
print(error_train[-1])
print(error_test[-1])
```

Comment: You make the assumption that code in the GPU is always faster than the CPU, and that is not true.\

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy  okay thank you, yes I made this assumption since (I think) it is quite well known that for deep learning model traning, GPU is really efficient. But maybe in my context it is not relevant to use GPU.. Do you know why ?

Comment: GPUs don't accelerate all workloads, you probably need a larger model to benefit from GPU acceleration. If the model is too small then the serial overheads are bigger than computing a forward/backward pass and you get negative performance gains.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for the answer!